# Put data side by side after the end of the csv file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro who allows me to import data of several csv file into a workbook containing several sheets :

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportCSVs()
'Import all CSV files from a folder into separate sheets

Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook

Set wbMST = ActiveWorkbook

'Update the path to your CSV files below. Add your-username and your-folder
'Don't remove the the final \ from the file path

fPath = "C:\Users\your-username\Documents\your-folder\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")

    Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)
        ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)

        fCSV = Dir
    Loop

Set wbCSV = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I would like to get each csv file into the same Excel file, thus, when a csv is finish, go to the column just after (A, B, C....)

Hope that's possible with the existing code...

Comment: Could you clarify what is "go to the column just after (A, B, C....)"?

Comment: @Beegees  please clarify which sheet of csv?, it contain more or single sheet?

Comment: @Ashok the csv file type can only contain one sheet.

Comment: @Beegess is there any value in A B C Column or keeping empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes all csv's have data in every column of top row

```
Sub ImportCSVs()
 'Import all CSV files from a folder into separate sheets

 Dim fPath   As String
 Dim fCSV    As String
 Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
 'Dim wbMST   As Workbook
 Dim target as range

 'Set wbMST = ActiveWorkbook
  set target = activeworkbook.worksheets(1).range("a1")

 'Update the path to your CSV files below. Add your-username and your-folder
 'Don't remove the the final \ from the file path

 fPath = "C:\Users\your-username\Documents\your-folder\"
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")

Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)
    'ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)
    wbcsv.sheets(1).usedrange.copy target
   set target = target.offset(0,target.currentregion.columns.count +1)
    '=======================New Line
     wbcsv.close False
     '==========End New line
    fCSV = Dir
Loop

 Set wbCSV = Nothing

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: I think he wanted import csv files into single workbook with multiplesheets

Comment: it works great, thanks.  I don't know why, but the macro creates sheets that I don't need and the sheet with all information

Comment: Now, I have one sheet with a csv by column on the same sheet, that's great, but others sheets are created, the problem is that I have to treat 80 csv files, I have to close 80 files that I don't need.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

this code probably will satisfy your condition and also code added to renaming the sheets.

```
Sub ImportCSVs()
'Import all CSV files from a folder into separate sheets

Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook

Set wbMST = ThisWorkbook

'Update the path to your CSV files below. Add your-username and your-folder
'Don't remove the the final \ from the file path

fPath = "C:\Users\your-username\Documents\your-folder\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.CSV")

    Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)
      wbCSV.ActiveSheet.Copy wbMST.ActiveSheet
      With wbMST
      Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = Left(fCSV, 6)
      'Sheets.Add
      End With
        fCSV = Dir
    Loop

Set wbCSV = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```